# How to pass field value from one model object to another?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Oh my... It is kind of a basic question, but I tried many solutions, but nothing works for me and I cannot find the similar question to mine...

I have two models:

```
class ForQuery(models.Model):
    id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    dep_sch = models.ForeignKey('DepDict', models.DO_NOTHING, 
    db_column='dep_sch', blank=True, null=True)
    code_dep_sch = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, 
    null=True)

class DepDict(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(primary_key=True, 
    max_length=35)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

I have all minimal meta for these Models incuding get_absolute_url and **str** . I have defined url for the function in view which I am using in the template.
I am matching both models by department in DepDict and dep_sch in ForQuery and in the template, based on this match I can print easily the code for the dartment, like so:

```
        {% for d in c%}
            {% if forquery.dep_station == d %}
                {{ d.code }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Now, based on this match, I cannot save referenced field code from  DepDict to field code_dep_sch from ForQuery. How would I approach this task? My view function looks like this so far:

```
class DirDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=ForQuery
    def get_context_data(self, **qwargs):
        content = super(MetalDetailView, self).get_context_data(**qwargs)
        content['c'] = DepDict.objects.all()
        self.code_dep_sch = c.code #this didn't work
        self.save()
        return conObject
```

Trying to using object.field_name doesn't work...
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to store that code in `ForQuery` model, where you can directly access it from ForeignKey relation using a property method or just a normal instance method:

```
class ForQuery(models.Model):
    id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    dep_sch = models.ForeignKey('DepDict', models.DO_NOTHING, 
    db_column='dep_sch', blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def code_dep_sch(self):
       if self.dep_sch:
          return self.dep_sch.code
       return ''
```

and use it in template:

```
{{ object.code_dep_sch }}
```

### Alternative solution

If you do not want to use a property method or a function in general, then [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) the `code` with `ForQuery` queryset, like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

class DirDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=ForQuery
    queryset = ForQuery.objects.annotate(code=F('dep_sch__code'))

# template

{{ object.code }}
```

### Update based on comments

In that case probably you should override the `ForQuery` save method:

```
class ForQuery(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.dep_sch:
          self.code_dep_sch = self.dep_sch.code
        super(ForQuery, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you ruddra. You helping me constantly to figure out my questions. If you need a help ever, please let me know. I'm trying to comprehend your suggestions and I believe, I didn't describe the question clear and confused you. I create query from the form and post it to database, in the ForQuery, there is a field 'code_dep_school', it is empty. I would like to update it each time after creating ForQuery drawing data from the field 'code' which is in DepDict model. Do you think I can achieve this result with your suggestions? Because it seems your solution goes only in ForQuery model.

Comment: If not, could you please boot me to the right direction... because there are so much information, but I cannot find any related information to my question. It's amazing how structured django is, but sometimes it leads to difficulties of finding right solution.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I am assuming everytime you create an instance of ForQuery, you would like to update the `code_dep_sch`. I have updated the answer according to this, please have a look.

Comment: I think this is the solution. I will find an article about overriding methods in Django. It seems that it is a necessity skill, if the program somehow gets out of the box, standards, even a little bit. I wish you only the best and thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry... The solution is a little off...  The thing is that "code" field comes from different Model... not from ForQuery, but from DepDict model... And I looked up for overriding methods for saving, but they are all about modifying method of the same one model,not bringing in other model... So I might seem as very insistive person, but that's just because I looked up through many many articles and nothing seems relates to my question. But the question, on the surface seems simple, but still I cannot find any information :(

Comment: the closest article was explaining how to copy whole column from one model to other model, by python-cmd line... But by idea, is only copy data from the field from DepDict model to ForQuery model on creating new data.

Comment: Again, I do not prefer duplicate data and I have already pointed that out on how to get data from `DepDict` to `ForQuery`, which should be an efficient solution(especially the second solution). If you are overriding `save()` method, then _The thing is that "code" field comes from different Model_ you can't avoid it unfortunatly. Either you need change your model design, or accept as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I tried to add foreign key between 2 tables, but my url started to conflict with "related name" and brought me more troubles... I will try to implement one of your solutions which are above. Thank you